# Problema al agregar items a una array

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Tengo una función que sirve para agregar números consecutivos a un array al hacer click en un button, este numero consecutivo lo envia a una peticion http para actualizar un formulario, esto se actualiza cada que el usuario da click en guardar.
Pero en lugar de agregar los números así:

`[1,2,3...]`

Los reemplaza
primero agrega 1

```
[1]
```

Pero al añadir mas números elimina el 1 y agrega el [2]
y no me actualiza el formulario

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  getAuditoriaAction,
  getListPuntosAction,
  getLogPuntosAction,
  getPuntoAction,
} from "../../redux/Auditoria/AuditoriaD";
import "../../css/index.css";

const Prellenado = () => {
  const url = "https://mysite.mx/api/logAuditoria";

  const styles = useStyles();
  const { idAuditoria } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cookies = new Cookies();

  var consecutivo = 1;
  var arraypControlLog = [];
  var arraypControl = [];

  const auditoria = useSelector((v) => v.auditoria.objAuditoria);

  const puntosControl = useSelector((v) => v.auditoria.arrayPuntos);

  const [logpuntosControl, setLogpuntosControl] = useState([]);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 

  const [registro, setRegistro] = useState({
    idAuditoria: idAuditoria,
    consecutivo: parseInt(consecutivo),
    opcion: "",
    justificacion: "",
  });

  const getData=async()=>{
    dispatch(getAuditoriaAction(cookies.get("IdUser"), idAuditoria));

    //carga los 236 puntos
    dispatch(getListPuntosAction());

    //llenar array con numeros consecutivos
    llenarArrayCat();
  };

  const llenarArrayCat = () => {
    for (const x of puntosControl) {
      arraypControl.push(x.consecutivo);
    }
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();

    cargarNpunto(consecutivo); 
  }, []);


  const cargarNpunto = (consecutivo) => {
    arraypControlLog.push(consecutivo);

    console.log(arraypControlLog);

    console.log(arraypControlLog.length);

     if (arraypControlLog.length === 1) {
      getNextpunto(1);  
    }

    //si no, cargar el siguiente punto
    else {         
      if (arraypControlLog.length < arraypControl.length) {
        getNextpunto(consecutivo);
      }
    } 
  };

 const getNextpunto = async (consecutivo) => {
    console.log(consecutivo);
    setData([]);

    await axios
      .get(
        "https://mysite.mx/api/puntoscontrol" +
          `/${consecutivo}`
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setData(res.data);
      });
  };
  
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setRegistro((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const guardar = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
   peticionPost();
  };
  
const peticionPost = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    await axios
      .post(url, registro)
      .then((response) => {
        consecutivo = response.data.consecutivo + 1;   

        //enviar el siguiente numero consecutivo
        cargarNpunto(consecutivo);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        swal({
          title: "error",
          text: error.request.response,
          icon: "error",
          button: "Cerrar",
        });
        console.log(error.response.data);
        console.log(error.request);
        console.log(error.message);
      });
    setLoading(false);
  };
  
  return (
    <div className={styles.root}>
      <Contenedor />
      <div className={styles.content}>
        <div className={styles.toolbar}> </div>
        <section className="content">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="card card-default">
              <div className="card-header">
                {auditoria.map((item) => (
                  <>
                    <Grid container spacing={1}>
                      <Grid item xs={12} md={12} lg={4}>
                       Ususario: {item.codigo} - {item.nombre}
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={12} md={12} lg={4}>
                        Area: {item.cod_area} - {item.area}
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={12} md={12} lg={4}>
                        Zona: {item.zona}
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </>
                ))}
              </div>

              {/*   {arraypControlLog.length===0?
              <> 
                <NoPunto key={idAuditoria} consecutivo={1} />
              </>
              :null
              } */}

              <form onSubmit={guardar}>
                <div className="card-body font-weight-bold">
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                      <div className="form-group-sm">
                        {data ? (
                          <>
                            {data.map((item) => (
                              <Grid container spacing={1}>
                                <Grid item xs={12} md={12} lg={12}>
                                  <div className="text-primary">Nº:</div>
                                  {item.noPunto}
                                </Grid>

                                <Grid item xs={12} md={12} lg={12}>
                                  <div className="text-primary">
                                    Punto de Control:
                                  </div>
                                  <p className="textos">{item.puntoControl}</p>
                                </Grid>

                                <Grid item xs={12} md={12} lg={12}>
                                  <div className="text-primary">
                                    Criterios de Cumplimiento:
                                  </div>
                                  <p className="textos">{item.criterio}</p>
                                </Grid>

                                <Grid item xs={12} md={12} lg={12}>
                                  <div className="text-primary">Nivel:</div>
                                  <p className="textos">{item.nivel}</p>
                                </Grid>

                                <Grid item xs={12} md={12} lg={3}>
                                  <div className="text-primary">Opción:</div>
                                  <select
                                    required
                                    name="opcion"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                  >
                                    <option value={0}> - Seleccione - </option>
                                    <option value={"SI"}>SI</option>
                                    <option value={"NO"}>NO</option>
                                    <option value={"NA"}>N/A</option>
                                  </select>
                                </Grid>

                                <Grid item xs={12} md={12} lg={12}>
                                  <div className="text-primary">
                                    Justificación:
                                  </div>
                                  <p className="textos">{item.justificacion}</p>
                                  <textarea
                                    required
                                    className="form-control"
                                    id="justificacion"
                                    rows="3"
                                    name="justificacion"
                                    autoComplete="off"
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                  />
                                </Grid>
                              </Grid>
                            ))}
                          </>
                        ) : (
                          <>
                            <div className="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                              Cargando
                            </div>
                          </>
                        )}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="card-footer">
                  <button
                    disabled={loading ? true : false}
                    className="btn btn-primary active float-right"
                    type="submit"
                  >
                    {loading ? "Espere..." : "Siguiente"}
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Prellenado;
```

Comment: Acabo de probar tu código tal y como está y no sucede lo que mencionas.

Comment: @JonatanLavado hola he modificado el codigo tal como lo tengo en mi aplicacion, para que se entienda mejor la logica de lo que estoy tratando de hacer

Comment: Aquí te dejo una [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hooks-demo-ynhvur?file=index.js) con una solución, espero que te sirva. Básicamente, debes usar hooks para las variables `consecutivo` y tal. Pero aún así, hay algo de desorden en tu código. Espero que la respuesta que te doy te sirva de guía.